# What's the difference in value of Trigger context variables new and old?

Tags: trigger, before-trigger, after-trigger

I have a confusion please can anyone solve it. I know it is silly but I am new to Salesforce so I need help.

In `before update` and `after update` what will be the difference between the values of `Trigger.new` and `Trigger.old`. For eg. If I update the value of name then in `before update` what will be the value and in `after update` what will the trigger.new and old contain.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's not gonna be modifications in the context variables in between `before` and `after` triggering, for ex. the new context variable is gonna be the same in `before update` that in `after update`. Most noticeable thing (a part of [where/when can be used](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm)) is that you can modify `new` records in the before and the changes are gonna be applied in the data.

You use `before` usually when there is some work to be done before updating the record, usually some kind of validation that cannot be done using validation rules. And you use `after` when the work has to be done after, usually some kind of data propagation or recalculation.

Comment: Changing the Name of an object in an "update" DML operation will mean the Trigger.old version has the original Name and the Trigger.new version has the new Name.

Comment: @PhilW I mean that there is not gonna be any difference between new in before update and new in after update. But I understand your point, I going to edit the answer. Thanks, Phil.

Comment: I would say that there can be a difference between Trigger.new in before compared with in after phase - not only could the before phase trigger update the Trigger.new instance(s) itself, but I believe formula field values will be calculated/re-calculated on entry to the after phase trigger. Not 100% sure on that though.

Comment: Thank you for clearing my doubt

Answer (score 1):

Please take this [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro) to find out about triggers.

For updates, Trigger.old data represents the objects' state BEFORE any changes were made, whereas Trigger.new represents the objects' state with the requested changes incorporated into them. What is more, you can make further changes to the objects, in the trigger during the "before" phase, by updating the Trigger.new object fields.

The other types of event (insert, delete, undelete etc.) use these properties subtly differently. You can find out more by doing the trailhead.